# Next occurrence of something, down the DOM tree

Tags: jquery

I'm having the hardest time trying to reference the next occurrence of an element with an ID containing a specific string.

Basically, I have a link, and I need to `show()` the NEXT div acting as a container for editing.

```
<div>
<a href="#" id="link-1">Link</a> // go from here
</div>

<div id="form-container-1" class="hidden"> // to here
<form>
...
</form>
```

Important to note: I'm not just targeting one `id` ... the purpose of the "1" within the form-container `id` is because there are several. I'm using the "contains" selector `id*="form-container"`

Comment: try next() for next, and children() for any ... wait for it... children. Visit the jQuery website for documentation and examples.

Comment: Why haven't you browsed through the jQuery documentation?

Comment: IDs are unique so if you know the ID you can just use `$('#id')`...

Comment: It's my fault for not explaining that I know ID's are unique... hence the "1" on the end. I'm using the "contains" short selector.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to dynamically find the correct form to show based on the id then something like:

```
$('a').click( function() {
   formId = $(this).attr('id').split('-')[1];
   $('#form-container-'+formId).show();
});
```

Alternatively, if you want to find the next form after each link:

```
$('a').click( function() {
   $(this).next('form').show();
});
```

Both of these, it would be advisable to add a unique class to links that will show forms and update the selectors accordingley.

Comment: This is more like it. Very much what I'm doing... however, it's not working the way I'm hoping it would. Possibly the "id" reference?

Comment: `attr` was what was missing. I was just coming back to say something. Also, in this case, index starts at 1... so it would be 2.

Answer (score 1):

If it directly proceeds the current item, then  will work.

Try using a combination of [parent()](http://jqapi.com/#p=parent) and [next()](http://jqapi.com/#p=parent) then.  This way you will be able to reference the containing `div` and then find the next `div`.

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/PdatP/

jQuery:

```
$('a').click(function(){
   $(this).parent().next().show(); 
});
```

Comment: Up above is exactly how it's laid out... and `next` doesn't work. `this` is the `a` link and I need to be able to reference the next div so I can unhide it.

Answer (score 1):

This will get the next sibling and show that element

```
    $('#link-1').next().show();
```

if its not exactly the next element you can use `siblings` method like;

```
   $('#link-1').siblings('#form-container-1').show();
```

Or if you want to show all elements that contain `form-container` in their ids

```
   $('#link-1').siblings('[id*="form-container"]').show();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#link-1").parent().next().show();
```